# how to use this function in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-deployment

```js
function College() {
    return (
   const close = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
      for(var i=0; i<close.length; i++){
      close[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
});
};
    <div className="College">
      <h2 className="projects__title" id="college">College Projects</h2>
    <div className="projects container mt-5">
            <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-header">
                    <p className="text-right mr-2 mt-2 close">X</p>
                    <h3 className="card-title mt-3">Summer Internship</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ChittojiMuraliSreeKrishna/images/main/images/college/cs5.png" alt="" className="card-img-top" />
                    <p className="card-text">I have done a dynamic messaging website named smart radio which uses HTML, CSS, javascript as frontend, PHP as backend, MySQL store the information & googleTextToSpeech to convert the messages to speech, this has users and admins, users send the messages by logging inWhile admins have the right to play or Delete messages</p>
                    <div className="card-footer">
                    <a href="https://github.com/ChittojiMuraliSreeKrishna/collegeProjects/tree/main/summerinternship/smartradio"
                  className="codebtn">CODE</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header">
                    <p className="text-right mr-2 mt-2 close">X</p>
                    <h3 className="card-title mt-3">Mini Project</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body"> 
                    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ChittojiMuraliSreeKrishna/images/main/images/college/cs9.jpg" alt="" className="card-img-top" />
                    <p className="card-text">I have done my mini-project on IOT named armySecuritySystem which sends co-ordinates by SMS or mail whenever the motion is detected, in this i have used PIR-sensor(HCSR-501), wifi-module(ESP8266), gsm-module(SIM800L), GPS-module(SIM28ML), so that when the PIR-sensor gets motion it wakes the system to send the message of the particular
                    location</p>
                    <div className="card-footer">
                    <a href="https://github.com/ChittojiMuraliSreeKrishna/collegeProjects/tree/main/miniProject" 
                    className="codebtn">CODE</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default College;
```

1. when i click on close, function in react its working only once in local server,
2. but when i deploy it on gh-pages, its not at all working
3. is there any other way of handling this in react?

[console.log shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kn5o.png)

Comment: May be there is a best React like implementation of your function with onClick event for example.
To help you it would be nice if we can see your component code.

Comment: Direct DOM manipulations are very anti-pattern in React, use/attach `onClick` handlers to the elements instead. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html.